# C/C++ undefined reference for sqlite3's functions using CLion with CMAKE

Tags: sqlite, cmake, cross-platform, clion

CMAKE's file has this code:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6) 
project(HelloSqliteC)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.c)
add_executable(HelloSqliteC ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

The file main.c has this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sqlite3.h>

int main() {
   sqlite3 *db;
   int rc;

   rc = sqlite3_open("database.db", &db);

   if (rc) {
       fprintf(stderr, "Can't open database: %s!\n",      sqlite3_errmsg(db));
   } else {
       fprintf(stderr, "Opened database successfully!\n");
   }

   sqlite3_close(db);
   return 0;
}
```

When I've trying compiling:

```
/home/marcus/ide/clion/clion-2016.3.1/bin/cmake/bin/cmake --build      /home/marcus/projects/native/HelloSqliteC/cmake-build-debug --target   HelloSqliteC -- -j 4
[ 50%] Building C object CMakeFiles/HelloSqliteC.dir/main.c.o
[100%] Linking C executable HelloSqliteC
CMakeFiles/HelloSqliteC.dir/main.c.o: In function `main':
/home/marcus/projects/native/HelloSqliteC/main.c:13: undefined reference to `sqlite3_open'
/home/marcus/projects/native/HelloSqliteC/main.c:16: undefined reference to `sqlite3_errmsg'
/home/marcus/projects/native/HelloSqliteC/main.c:21: undefined reference to `sqlite3_close'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/HelloSqliteC.dir/build.make:94: recipe for target     'HelloSqliteC' failed
make[3]: *** [HelloSqliteC] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target     'CMakeFiles/HelloSqliteC.dir/all' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/HelloSqliteC.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:79: recipe for target     'CMakeFiles/HelloSqliteC.dir/rule' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/HelloSqliteC.dir/rule] Error 2
Makefile:118: recipe for target 'HelloSqliteC' failed
make: *** [HelloSqliteC] Error 2
```

I tried solve this issue using different ways, but no success.
I'm using CLion C/C++, my OS is Ubuntu 16.04 and I install sqlite3 using autoconf.

For test, I used the main.c above and compiled in command line with "-l sqlite3" using GCC and I had success, but I want use CLion.

Help me, thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: I assume CLion has a dialog to add external libraries to you project. You'll need to do that for sqlite3. CLion will then properly rebuild the `CMakeLists.txt` for you.

Comment: @Olaf, no this is specifically a CLion usage issue

Comment: @nega: Did you read the dup? It is generic and also covers this issue. **How** to add li9braries is specific to the build-tool, but users are expected to figure out such things on their own. In other words: to RTFineM.

Comment: @olaf which is exactly what makes this not a dupe. OP has demonstrated he knows how to fix the link failure in the generic (command line) sense. but is asking specifically about how to fix it in CMake and or CLion.

Comment: @olaf my issue is about how to fix it it CLion in my question _For test, I used the main.c above and compiled in command line with "-l sqlite3" using GCC and I had success, but I want use CLion._

Comment: @mark42 i just gave CLion a quick spin. I didnt realize it was that simple of an IDE. see my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41251474/how-to-import-zeromq-libraries-in-cmake/41252437#41252437 but substitue sql3 for zmq.

Comment: @MarcusAdriano: We are not the CLion support forum. What did you try to fix it, why did it not work? What about the documentation did you not understand?

Comment: @nega if I understand, your answer I have put source code of the sqlite3 in my src folder?

Comment: @mark42 no i don't suggest that at all. read the question and answer again. compare the OP's `CMakeLists.txt` to the one i suggest in my answer.

Comment: @nega Hey, thanks, your post solve my problem too, but this solve target_link_libraries(projectName LINK_PUBLIC libraryName) and this is very simple.

Comment: If this is not a duplicate but specific to CLion, why are the tags [cmake] and [sqlite] used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this issue with this `target_link_libraries(HelloSqlite3 LINK_PUBLIC sqlite3)` or `target_link_libraries(projectName LINK_PUBLIC libraryName)`.

Answer (score 4):

I also use CLion C/C++. The OS is Ubuntu 18.04.
But I want to compile the `main.cpp`.
The `CMakelist.txt` is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
project(ProjectName)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
add_executable(student main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(ProjectName LINK_PUBLIC sqlite3)
```

It works successfully.

Comment: Such a simple solution to an issue that's dogged me for 3 days.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

CLion uses CMake for all the building and project configuration. You have to manually modify `CMakeLists.txt`. In fact this is a CMake question.

This line in your CMakeLists.txt will solve your problem:

```
add_compile_options(-l sqlite3)
```

But actually CMake has a more sophisticated dependency discovery system. Read [How To Find Libraries](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake:How_To_Find_Libraries) to learn this.

Comment: It's don't work =(. I'll read _How to Find Libraries_. Thanks.

Comment: Did you add add_compile_options before add_executable?